# Instagram API authorization is returning 400, but only for specific user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an Instagram client set up for our WordPress theme that allows users to authorize access to their own Instagram account.  We have many users using this feature, but I have one user that is getting the following JSON response when trying to authorize to receive a token:

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "There was an error with your request. Please try again."}
```

That's the response after clicking the "Authorize" button after navigating to the following url (with our actual client ID removed for this example):

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id={our client id}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Finstagram-auth&scope=basic&response_type=code&state=aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo3Nzc3Lz9wcF9yb3V0ZT0vaW5zdGFncmFtLWF1dGg&hl=en
```

Note: the localhost url isn't the issue, as this test works fine when I log into a different Instagram account.  It's only this user having this problem.

I can't find any reference of this specific error message after searching.